# Image not showing in browser on local server (Live server extension) but shows when opened from explorer

Tags: html

I am having problem in HTML . My Image is not showing in browser (Firefox) when html file is opened through live server extension (VS code).It throws a Security error that html file can't link to image. I want to use image as background.
My html file is folder in D: drive.

```
  Path = D:/myhtml/index.html
```

And my image is in F: drive

```
  Path = F:/mountain.png
```

my img tag is

`<img src="f:/mountain.png" alt="mountain"/>`
But when I open html file directly from file explorer image shows up.
Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: The standard URL syntax should be `<img src="file:///f:/mountain.png">`. Some browsers like Microsoft Edge might recognize "legacy" formats like a raw DOS file name, but Firefox doesn't. And obviously this will only work on your local machine. A server will usually not allow you to put files outside your site root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Live server in made to behave like a real web server (one that is online on the web, called via http(s), and does not have access to your local hard drive file system "the Windows way" with F: etc.

Going to F:// is only possible on your own machine and will never work online. Browsers have built in a way for you to browse your local files like that. Web servers don't have this feature.

Use HTML file paths, meant for the web server:

**Absolute path:** `https://example.com/images/mountain.png` (path to an online destination which could be another domain than yours)

**Relative path:** `images/mountain.png` (relative to where your html file is located on your own web server)

**Relative path to a folder outside of where your html is located:** `../../etc/images/mountain.png`